# Error al mostrar datos "Android/Java - JSONException"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

espero me puedan ayudar, error esta en " ***th.nombre as 'th_nombre'*** " de la sentencia SQL, en el PHP muestra correcto, pero cuando lo quiero mostrar en el aplicativo me salta este error ***JSONException***; pero si en el aplicativo omito la línea referente a " ***th.nombre as 'th_nombre'*** " , los datos si se muestran correctamente.

CODIGO PHP:

```
<?php
include '../conexion.php';
$numero_habitacion=$_GET['numero_habitacion'];

$consulta="SELECT numero_habitacion,th.nombre as 'th_nombre',imagen_habitacion,imagen_habitacion_bano,cantidad_personas_habitacion,terma,ducha,lampara,mesa_de_noche,
ropero,cantidad_camas_total,tipo_cama1,tipo_cama_2,tipo_cama_3,cantidad_TC1,cantidad_TC2,cantidad_TC3,sillas,tvycable,telefono,wifi,
vista_calle,estado_habitacion FROM habitacion h left join tipo_habitacion th on h.tp_habitacion = th.id_tipohabitacion where numero_habitacion ='$numero_habitacion'";

$resultado = $conexion-> query($consulta);

while ($fila=$resultado->fetch_array()){
    $datos[]= array_map(`utf8_encode`,$fila);
}

echo json_encode($datos);
$resultado -> close(); 
?>
```

CODIGO EN ANDROID PARA MOSTRAR (omito líneas de código, que son de los demás datos a mostrar):
LINEA DEL ERROR:  ***textViewTH.setText(jsonObject.getString("th_nombre"));***

```
private void MostrarHabitacion(String URL){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest= new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    textViewNH.setText(jsonObject.getString("numero_habitacion"));
                    textViewTH.setText(jsonObject.getString("th_nombre"));
                    textViewNP.setText(jsonObject.getString("cantidad_personas_habitacion"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mini_mensaje, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.miniContenedor));
                    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);
                    text.setText("ERROR del JSONException");
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setView(layout);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema `JSONException` que se genera en la línea de código:

```
textViewTH.setText(jsonObject.getString("th_nombre"));
```

puede indicar que el valor del campo `nombre` en tu tabla `tipo_habitacion` en algunos casos probablemente no existe, ya que **se lanza `JSONException` si no existe el valor o si existe la propiedad para la clave, pero su valor es null.**

Para evitar este problema, puedes definir un valor predeterminado como segundo parámetro en estos casos, por ejemplo una cadena vacía en caso de no existir el valor:

```
textViewTH.setText(jsonObject.getString("th_nombre", ""));
```